# HOME variable is not set

Tags: upstart, environment-variables

I have two servers, they're identical (I believe), production and staging servers.

And I have upstart script in `/etc/init/` folder.

```
description "Discoure process"

setuid deploy
setgid deploy

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  echo \"$HOME/.rbenv\"

  cd /home/deploy/discourse/current

  bundle exec bluepill load config/discourse.pill --no-privileged --base-dir tmp/bluepill --logfile log/bluepill.log
EOT
end script
```

On the staging server it works well, but when I'm running that script on production server then the HOME variable is empty, the code `echo "$HOME/.rbenv"` is evaluating to `"/.rbenv"`

What might be a problem here? Thanks

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but why not set it first, statically though?

Comment: Why the cumbersome bash script? It looks like (da)sh would interpret it perfectly fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598815/what-environment-variables-available-while-starting-the-script-using-init-d-boot) question on stackoverflow.com and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/271935) by user `grawity` on superuser.com

You should not use `$HOME` in `init.d`, because it is not clear which users home to use, until this user logs in.

Quote from [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html):

```
HOME
The system shall initialize this variable at the time of login to be a pathname
of the user's home directory. See <pwd.h>.
```

You can use little hack, to get home folder of user `myuser` in your script

```
su - myuser -c /usr/bin/env | grep HOME
```

It is better  to use script below, because usually there can be other `HOME_*` folders. Such as `JAVA_HOME` etc.

```
su - myuser -c /usr/bin/env | grep "^HOME="
```

Answer (score 8):

Seems like the $HOME is being interpreted before it goes to bash? I would try one of the following. Either add:

```
env HOME=/home/MyName
```

to the code just after the description.

Or move the code from inside the script block to another script file with:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

as line 1. Then have

```
exec /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Comment: The first suggestion doesn’t appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the `HOME` variable to be set (which solved my problem), you can explicitly set it with the `env` directive:

```
env HOME=/home/user
```

via https://askubuntu.com/a/1125244/160358