# How do you append to environment variable in Upstart?

Tags: upstart

I put the following in my /etc/init/myjob.conf file but it doesn't seem to work

```
env PATH=$PATH:/mnt/data/src
env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/mnt/progs/link
```

Is it possible to somehow append to an environmental variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work"? If you explain to us what you are trying to do, we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> export PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"

You should add this in **~/.bashrc** file to work at every user session.

You should restart to see it working or try `. .bashrc` command to work without restart.

Comment: What does this have to do with upstart and why is it accepted?

Answer (score 2):

You can't append variables inside an upstart script, you need to use an external file and source it inside a script section:

create a **/etc/default/myjob** file with content like:

```
env PATH=$PATH:/mnt/data/src
env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/mnt/progs/link
export PATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

then in **/etc/init/myjob.conf** source it where you need it

```
script 
    . /etc/default/myjob
    exec command
end script
```

while this would look unnecessary complicated it is actually correct because an init script file is supposed to change between packages version while /etc/default/appname are configuration files and aren't overwritten by default

Answer (score 1):

You add them as `env VAR=foo` in your upstart config file:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following into your /etc/environment file:

```
PATH="/mnt/data/src:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

PYTHONPATH="/mnt/progs/link"
```

Of course, this method won't "append", but it shouldn't be necessary due to this are the main environment variables, and other applications should append to them.